# looking for a text pattern in all the files

Tags: replace, notepad++

We have got lot of files with the text like:

> create user user_name
>
> identified by crsny
>
> tablespace tab1

Is there anyway to search for   `identified by **** /n`
and then replace with `somethingelse` in **Notepad++**.

Comment: try the replace dialog `Ctrl + H`

Answer (score 1):

- Open the Find in Files tab (CTRL + SHIFT + F)
- Check the Regular Expression option (bottom of this window)
- Fill the directory path of your files on Directory field
- Check "In All sub-folders" option (if the path have subdirectories)
- Fill the field "Find what" with: `identified\s+by\s+.+`
- Fill the field "Replace with" with: `somethingelse`
- To be sure that it is right click on "Find All" button
- At last, click on "Replace in files"

Post note, if you are sure of the wanted text `identified by....` case, just mark the "Match Case" option

Answer (score -1):

Yes; use a standard regex in the Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). You'd probably want something like this in **Find what**:

```
^identified by (\S+)$
```

And then in **Replace with**, `\1`.

There are four major parts to this. First are the anchors: `^` matches a zero-width position at the start of a line, and `$` does the same thing at the end. `()` makes a *capturing subgroup* (automatically indexed from 1 on up by order in the string), which is then dropped into the replacement string with `\1` (or `\2`, or any other subgroup index with a backslash in front). Finally, `\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters, in lieu of a more specific validation that precisely matches all allowable usernames.

As Jorge suggests, you can use the same patterns in the Find in files tab to do the replacement on all files at a time, but you should probably do this after checking on one file first.